# Typescript cannot find name 'Firebase'

Tags: typescript, angular, firebase

I get typescript errors when trying to build my project which includes angularfire2 and firebase.  Here are the packages:

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
"firebase": "^2.4.2",
```

And here are the errors:

```
[10:58:34] Finished 'build.html_css' after 4.51 s
[10:58:34] Starting 'build.js.dev'...
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.d.ts(8,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Firebase'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/database/database.d.ts(9,31): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Firebase'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth.d.ts(10,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseCredentials'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth.d.ts(13,16): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseAuthData'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth.d.ts(14,29): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseCredentials'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth.d.ts(14,59): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseAuthData'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth_backend.d.ts(4,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseCredentials'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth_backend.d.ts(8,44): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseAuthData'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth_backend.d.ts(9,25): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseAuthData'.
c:/Dev/daybreak/node_modules/angularfire2/providers/auth_backend.d.ts(11,38): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'FirebaseCredentials'.
```

If I open database.d.ts in node_modules, there is not an import for 'Firebase' so I can see why this would fail..  where is it expecting to get 'Firebase' from?

```
import { FirebaseListObservable } from '../utils/firebase_list_observable';
import { FirebaseObjectObservable } from '../utils/firebase_object_observable';
import { FirebaseListFactoryOpts } from '../utils/firebase_list_factory';
import { FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts } from '../utils/firebase_object_factory';
export declare class FirebaseDatabase {
    private fbUrl;
    constructor(fbUrl: string);
    list(urlOrRef: string | Firebase, opts?: FirebaseListFactoryOpts): FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    object(urlOrRef: string | Firebase, opts?: FirebaseObjectFactoryOpts): FirebaseObjectObservable<any>;
}
```

I don't get why it's even checking typings in node_modules.. it's part of my exclude in tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "typings/browser.d.ts",
    "typings/browser",
    "src"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this into .ts your file ==> import { AngularFire, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';